# Unit testing of DAO classes using JUnit and Mockito

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, junit4, dao

I have DaoImpl class:

```
public class MessageTypeDaoImpl implements MessageTypeDao{

    public int[] createMessageTypes(final List<MessageType> messageTypes){
        String sql = "INSERT INTO MSG_TYPE VALUES(?, ?)";
        return jdbcTemplate.batchUpdate(sql, new BatchPreparedStatementSetter() {
            public void setValues(PreparedStatement ps, int i) throws SQLException {
                MessageType messageType = messageTypes.get(i);
                ps.setString(1, messageType.getMessageId());
                ps.setString(2, messageType.getMessageName());
            }

            public int getBatchSize(){
                return messageTypes.size();
            }
    });
}
```

And my test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class MessageTypeDaoImplTest {

@Mock
private JdbcTemplate jdbcTemplate;

@Spy
@InjectMocks
MessageTypeDaoImpl messageTypeDaoImpl;
@Before
public void setUp(){
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);
}
@Test
public void createMessageTypes() {
    int[] returnCount = new int[1];
    List<MessageType> messageTypeList = new ArrayList<MessageType>();
    messageTypeList.add(getSampleMessageType());
    messageTypeDaoImpl.createMessageTypes(messageTypeList);
    doReturn(returnCount).when(messageTypeDaoImpl).createMessageTypes(messageTypeList);
    assertEquals(returnCount, messageTypeDaoImpl.createMessageTypes(messageTypeList));
}
}

public MessageType getSampleMessageType(){
    return new MessageType("messageTypeId", "messageTypeName");
}
```

Test is successful but when I run junit test with coverage it shows `public void setValues()` method is not being covered, hence my overall unit test line coverage is below the requirements. Can we cover that part? And if yes then how we do it? Thanks.

Comment: Don't mock JdbcTemplate, use a real instance. You probably already have a real instance in your Spring container. Note that JdbcTemplate has dependencies, for instance: DataSource. You will likely need to mock the DataSource and inject it into JdbcTemplate. You can probably let Spring inject if for you by: in your unit test have a member variable of type DataSource, and use the @MockBean annotation on it.

Comment: And what is the point of calling ` messageTypeDaoImpl.createMessageTypes(messageTypeList);` before that doReturn().when() statement? And: why are you using a spy here? It seems like you are throwing together various elements of Mockito, without knowing what they are actually used for?

Comment: @GhostCat I called createMessageTypes because if I don't do it the method won't be called and there will be no code coverage for it. I am required to make sure I have code coverage as high as possible(class % and line % coverage in IntelliJ IDE). About Spy annotation, I had issues calling methods(for code coverage again) and someone on stackoverflow said we can make make an instance close to real one(or half mocked) and call the method. I haven't done unit testing that much before, not to mention mockito. So I am trying to understand how I can make it work together.

Answer (score 4):

Try this below code spinet. I will cover the code as well. I check it from my end, and it worked.

```
int[] batchInsert=new int[] {1,2};
        try {

            Mockito.doAnswer(invocationOnMock -> {

                PreparedStatement ps = Mockito.mock(PreparedStatement.class);
                BatchPreparedStatementSetter psr = invocationOnMock.getArgument(1);
                psr.setValues(ps, 1);
                return batchInsert;

            }).when(jdbcTemplate).batchUpdate(anyString(),  Mockito.any(BatchPreparedStatementSetter.class));
```